# Как положить JSON данные в foriegn key таблицы

Tags: java, reactjs, post, hibernate, jpa

Есть 2 pojo:

**TASK**

```
public class Task {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "title")
private String tilte;

@JsonIgnore
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="project_id")
private Project project;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="task_status_id")
private TaskStatus taskStatus;
```

}

**Project**

```
public class Project {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "project", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Task> tasks;

@JsonIgnore
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "projects")
private List<User> users;
```

}

Использую на фронте react. Хочу создать новый task, упаковываю post запрос и отправляю. MySQL жалуется: Column 'project_id' cannot be null.

JSON данные упаковываю в виде:
{"name":newTask,"title":"newTaskTitle","project":[{"id":1,"name":"projectName"}], "taskStatus": [{"id":1, "name":"taskStatusName"}]}

В классе Task есть два foreign ключа(для Project и для TaskStatus), foreign ключ для TaskStatus видит. Думаю проблема в маппинге.

Comment: В таске есть  колонка:
@JoinColumn(name="project_id")

Но в Project ее нет :
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

Comment: параметр project_id хранится в бд в талице Task в качесвте foreign key. Как о нем стоит упоминать в pojo по вашему?